# Using php array_multisort twice to sort the same array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-multisort

I have a large multidimensional array and I want to sort it twice by date using     `array_multisort` and get the last 3 arrays from each sort

I could create a duplicate of the array but it seems a waste when all I want is 3 arrays from it

```
$rows = array(
    array(...),
    array(...),
    ...
);
```

I create the arrays to be sorted like this

```
foreach($rows as $key => $row) {
    $submit_date[$key] = $row['Submit_Date'];
    $view_date[$key] = $row['View_Date'];
}
```

On this iteration of the sort, everything works as I expect

```
array_multisort($view_date, SORT_DESC, $rows);
$viewed = array_slice(array_unique($rows, SORT_REGULAR), 0, 3, true);
```

but on this one which is run straight after, I get different results to what I expect

```
array_multisort($submit_date, SORT_DESC, $rows);
$unlisted = array_slice(array_unique($rows, SORT_REGULAR), 0, 3, true);
```

I can't sort on both sort arrays because there will be occasions where $view_date array will have null values.

Is there a way I can use the same array to sort by view date, get the last 3 rows then sort the array by submit date then get the last 3 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your first multisort messed up the order of `$rows`.
A dummy array should do the trick: `$temp = $rows;`

Comment: That's what I thought but was hoping i could resort the original array

Comment: Sure, you could put a `sort($rows);` before each multisort.